# What are the rules for threading a function over a vector in R?

Tags: r, lapply

I have some code which I call with two vectors of different length, lets call them A and B. However, I wrote the function having in mind a single element of A with the expectation that it will be automatically threaded over A. To be concrete,

```
A <- rnorm(5)
B <- rnorm(30)

foo <- function(x,B){
    sum( cos(x*B) ) # calculate sum_i cos(x*B[i])
}

sum( exp(foo(A,B)) ) # expecting this to calculate the exponent for each A[j] and add over j
```

I need to get

```
Σ_j exp( Σ_i cos(A[j]*B[i])
```

and not

```
Σ_ij exp(cos(A[j]*B[i])) OR  exp(cos(Σ_ij A[j]*B[i]))
```

I suspect that the last R expression is ambiguous, since the declaration of foo does not know B is always a vector. What are the formal rules and am I right to worry about the ambiguity?

Comment: Do you need `sum(sapply(A, function(x) foo(x, B)))`

Comment: My first guess was yes, but running it in R gives a different answer from my sum( exp(foo(A,B)) ). So what is one computing is what the other? @akrun

Comment: `foo(A, B)` returns a single value

Comment: Yes, and also a surprise, to be honest. The question is what is the rule?

Comment: IN your function foo, it is doing the `A*B` which would work only if there is a recycling when the length is a multiple of 'B', here 100 is a multiple of 5

Comment: You can check the difference with `(1:5) * (1:20)` and `(1:5) * (1:21)` now you get a warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to loop over the 'A', then use `sapply` , and apply the `foo` on each of the elements of 'A' with anonymous function call and get the `sum` of the output vector

```
sum(exp(sapply(A, function(x) foo(x, B))))
```

---

In the OP's example with the expression `foo(A, B)`, the product `A*B` is computed first, and since the lengths of A and B are unequal, the recycling rule takes priority. There is no error message coming out, just because by pure luck the vector length of one is a multiple of the other.

Comment: @Kostas the `outer` one would give the same result as `sum(exp(cos(do.call(`*`, expand.grid(A, B)))))`

Comment: @Kostas ok, in that you don't need a cartesian product

Answer (score 1):

You can also `Vectorize` the `x` input. I think this is what you were expecting. At the end of the day, this will work it's way down to an `mappy()` implementation which is a multivariate `sapply`, so probably best to just do it yourself as with the solution from akrun.

```r
foo2 <- Vectorize(foo, "x")

sum(exp(foo2(A, B)))
```

---

The "formal rules" as you put them is quite simply how R does `help("Arithmetic")`.

> The binary operators return vectors containing the result of the element by element operations. If involving a zero-length vector the result has length zero. Otherwise, the elements of shorter vectors are recycled as necessary (with a warning when they are recycled only fractionally). The operators are + for addition, - for subtraction, * for multiplication, / for division and ^ for exponentiation.

So when you use `x*B`, it is doing element-wise multiplication. Nothing changes when you pass `A` into the function instead of `x`.

Simply go through your lines one at a time.

1. `x*B` will be a vector of length max(length(x, B)). When they are not of the same length, R will recycle elements of the shorter vector (i.e., repeat them).
2. `cos(x*B)` will be a vector of the same length as step (1), but now the cosine of that value.
3. `sum( cos(x*B) )` will sum that vector, returning a single number.
4. `foo(A,B)` does steps (1) through (3), but with your defined `A` and `B`. Note that in your example `A` is *recycled* 6 times to get to the length of `B`. In other words, what you entered as `A` is being used as `rep(A, 6)` in the multiplication step. Nothing about a function definition in R says that `foo(A,B)` should be repeated for each element of vector A. So it behaves literally as you wrote it, basically swapping in `A` for `x` in the function code.
5. `exp(foo(A,B))` will take the result from `foo` from step 3 (which is a scalar) and raise it to an exponent.
6. `sum( exp(foo(A,B)) )` does nothing, since step (5) is a scalar, there is nothing to sum.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a solution. I am looking for an explanation of the formal rule governing this.

Comment: It is how R does math. I added an update and hopefully what you are looking for is within there somewhere. To put it simply, your expectation that it would "automatically be threaded over A" is just not how R works, and that is consistent throughout the language. The rules are just conceptually understanding how its functions and arithmetic operations work.

Comment: Ok, maybe my confusion stemmed from not having a clear idea of just how type-loose is R compared to C++. R reads the definition of foo and will interpret it later in accordance with whatever types you pass in later. Even C++ templates will not usually give you such variability... "sum" is one thing when x is a scalar, another thing when its a vector, and if x and B are both vectors will do an element-wise multiplication first - but recycling for unequal length - and fail if unequal length.

Comment: "expectation it would be automatically be threaded over A is just not how R works" - I disagree. It does automatically apply scalar functions element-wise, but this rule applies only if some other rule with higher priority does not come in. In this case, * operator wants to combine two vectors into one and obviously has a higher priority than foo.

Comment: Yeah that is fair. Regardless, hope you sorted out what you were looking for.